# C++ program to count repeated words in a cstring

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, c-strings

I've been working on a C++ program, I've made the logic but I'm unable to execute it. The question is:

Task:  Write a program, using functions only, with the following features.

1. Program reads paragraph(s) from the file and stores in a string.
2. Then program counts the occurrence of each word in the paragraph(s) and stores all words with their number of occurrences.
3. If that word has appeared more than one time in whole string, it should store the word only once along its total occurrences.
4. The output described in above (in part 3) must be stored in a new file.
   Sample input:
   is the is and the is and the and is and only that is

Sample output:

is  5

the 3

and 4

only    1

that    1

I'll cut short to Occurrence program that I've written,
My logic is to store token into character array and then compare that array with main character array and do the increment:

```
 void occurances() {
    char* string = getInputFromFile();
    char separators[] = ",.\n\t ";
    char* token;
    char* nextToken;
    char* temp[100];
    token = strtok_s(string, separators, &nextToken);
    cout << temp;
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while ((token != NULL)) {
        temp[i] = token;
        i++;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                if ((strcmp(token, *temp)) == 0) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            cout << temp << " : " << counter << endl;
        }
        if (token != NULL) {
            token = strtok_s(NULL, separators, &nextToken);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is preposterous I know that, But please anyone be kind enough to give me a clue, actually I'm new to C++ . Thank you

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of C-strings. Use an `std::unordered_map<>()` to count your words.

Comment: yes that would be easy but i'm strictly prohibited to use them at this stage

Comment: You're going to have to outline your requirements and restrictions more clearly, then. It's fine if this is homework. There's no reason to hide the fact. With the code I'm seeing, I'm not convinced this is even a C++ assignment.

Comment: What more from the standard library are you forbidden to use? Most of it? If so, please state everything you _are_ permitted to use.

Comment: yes i know that code looks ridiculous but considering the fact that i'm just a beginner please let it slide

Comment: If you want an answer that doesn't use certain parts of the standard library, you should also state all the parts that can't be used _or_ state all the parts that _can_ be used. How should we be able to know what we can use otherwise?

Comment: @TedLyngmo i can only use cstring library for this particular assignment i'm not allowed to use classes nor inbuilt functions.

Comment: _"i'm not allowed to use classes"_ - Does that mean that you are not allowed to make your own classes either? _"only cstring_" - So, `iostream` and `cstdio` is forbidden too?

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's right

Comment: @TedLyngmo this thing is made difficult on purpose

Comment: If you aren't allowed to create your own classes in a C++ course where you aren't allowed to use `std::string` to deal with strings, I would quit that course. It's the most ridiculous thing I've heard in a long time.

Comment: @TedLyngmo no I can use iostream conio.h fstream ctime ctring iomanip

Comment: @TedLyngmo classes coming up after this

Comment: ... ok, so it's one of those "Learn everything in the wrong order" type of courses. Sounds painful.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's right, it is the kind of system to stress individuals

Comment: @TedLyngmo on the internet i see many easy solutions and just wonder why I'm not taught that way

Answer (score 1):

If you store token into array this array should grow dynamically because the number of tokens is not known at the beginning. And according to the task description, you cannot use C++ standard containers, so, it is necessary to implement dynamic array manually, for example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

std::size_t increase_capacity_value(std::size_t capacity) {
    if (capacity == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (capacity < (SIZE_MAX / 2)) {
        return capacity * 2;
    }
    return SIZE_MAX;
}

bool increase_array_capacity(char**& tokens_array, std::size_t*& tokens_count, std::size_t& capacity) {
    const std::size_t new_capacity = increase_capacity_value(capacity);
    if (new_capacity <= capacity) {
        return false;
    }

    const std::size_t tokens_array_byte_size = new_capacity * sizeof(char*);
    char** const new_tokens_array = static_cast<char**>(std::realloc(tokens_array, tokens_array_byte_size));
    if (new_tokens_array == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    tokens_array = new_tokens_array;

    const std::size_t tokens_count_byte_size = new_capacity * sizeof(std::size_t);
    std::size_t* const new_tokens_count = static_cast<std::size_t*>(std::realloc(tokens_count, tokens_count_byte_size));
    if (new_tokens_count == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    tokens_count = new_tokens_count;
    capacity = new_capacity;
    return true;
}

bool add_token(char* token, char**& tokens_array, std::size_t*& tokens_count, std::size_t& array_size, std::size_t& array_capacity) {
    if (array_size == array_capacity) {
        if (!increase_array_capacity(tokens_array, tokens_count, array_capacity)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    tokens_array[array_size] = token;
    tokens_count[array_size] = 1;
    ++array_size;

    return true;
}

std::size_t* get_token_count_storage(char* token, char** tokens_array, std::size_t* tokens_count, std::size_t array_size) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
        if (std::strcmp(token, tokens_array[i]) == 0) {
            return tokens_count + i;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

bool process_token(char* token, char**& tokens_array, std::size_t*& tokens_count, std::size_t& array_size, std::size_t& array_capacity) {
    std::size_t* token_count_ptr = get_token_count_storage(token, tokens_array, tokens_count, array_size);
    if (token_count_ptr == nullptr) {
        if (!add_token(token, tokens_array, tokens_count, array_size, array_capacity)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        ++(*token_count_ptr);
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    char string[] = "is the is and the is and the and is and only that is";
    char separators[] = ",.\n\t ";

    std::size_t token_array_capacity = 0;
    std::size_t token_array_size = 0;
    char** tokens_array = nullptr;
    std::size_t* tokens_count = nullptr;

    char* current_token = std::strtok(string, separators);
    while (current_token != nullptr) {
        if (!process_token(current_token, tokens_array, tokens_count, token_array_size, token_array_capacity)) {
            break;
        }
        current_token = std::strtok(nullptr, separators);
    }

    // print the report only if all tokens were processed
    if (current_token == nullptr) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < token_array_size; ++i) {
            std::cout << tokens_array[i] << " : " << tokens_count[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::free(tokens_array);
    std::free(tokens_count);
}
```

[godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/45x4rhzqG)

Comment: okay what if i want to store any token once, in an array and then replace it with new word while deleting duplicates in character array

Answer (score 0):

> okay what if i want to store any token once, in an array and then replace it with new word while deleting duplicates in character array

It is also possible solution. But in general case, it is also necessary to allocate the memory dynamically for the current token. Because the lengths of tokens are also not known at the beginning:

```cpp
void replace_chars(char* str, const char* chars_to_replace) {
    while (str && *str != '\0') {
        str = std::strpbrk(str, chars_to_replace);
        if (str == nullptr) {
            break;
        }

        const std::size_t number_of_delimiters = std::strspn(str, chars_to_replace);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < number_of_delimiters; ++i) {
            str[i] = '\0';
        }

        str += number_of_delimiters;
    }
}

bool keep_token(char*& token_storage, const char* new_token) {
    if (new_token == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    const std::size_t current_token_len = token_storage ? std::strlen(token_storage) : 0;
    const std::size_t requried_token_len = std::strlen(new_token);

    if (token_storage == nullptr || current_token_len < requried_token_len) {
        token_storage =
            static_cast<char*>(std::realloc(token_storage, (requried_token_len + 1) * sizeof(char)));
        if (token_storage == nullptr) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    std::strcpy(token_storage, new_token);
    return true;
}

std::size_t count_tokens_and_replace(char* str, std::size_t str_len, const char* token) {
    std::size_t number_of_tokens = 0;
    std::size_t i = 0;

    while (i < str_len) {
        while (str[i] == '\0') ++i;

        if (std::strcmp(str + i, token) == 0) {
            replace_chars(str + i, token);
            ++number_of_tokens;
        }

        i += std::strlen(str + i);
    }

    return number_of_tokens;
}

int main() {
    char string[] = "is the is and the is and the and is and only that is";
    char separators[] = ",.\n\t ";

    const std::size_t string_len = std::strlen(string);
    replace_chars(string, separators);

    std::size_t i = 0;
    char* token = nullptr;

    while (true) {
        while (i < string_len && string[i] == '\0') ++i;

        if (i == string_len || !keep_token(token, string + i)) break;

        std::cout << token << " : " << count_tokens_and_replace(string + i, string_len - i, token) << std::endl;
    }

    std::free(token);
}
```

[godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/E9K893zv6)

But if it is known that the token length cannot be greater than `N`, it is possible to use the static array of chars to keep the current token. And it will allow to remove dynamic memory allocation from the code.